# text editor in java

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I want to make a webpage having some the options of microsoft word like bold, underline, insert image, table etc. to be displayed on webpage. I want a webpage in which user can create a word document or edit the word document. I used apache POI for creating, fetching word document. but it was not efficient. Does apache POI provide solution?  Are there any API or tool that we can use in java or javascript to make a word document editor?. Please provide solution.
than you in advance

Comment: I used CKEditor for this. I extracted the html output of formated text in javascript and displayed output html text on JSP.


http://nightly.ckeditor.com/17-01-17-07-06/full/samples

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want to work with Microsoft office, use JavaScript API for Office.

http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office

Comment: This would be better as comment.

Comment: @Raúl Although I agree more context could have been given. I think this is OK as an answer as it directly answers one of the questions from max.

Comment: I am looking after that API. I forgot to mention that i dont want any involvement of word document while my application is running. Once you complete editing or creating document it should be updated on jsp with the same formats and style as in word document. Is that possible with this API?

Comment: @max There's a `save()` method that saves the document. At which point (assuming your application can handle the document) the document will be updated and you can continue doing whatever it is you're going to do with it. I'm basing this purely off the documentation though.

Comment: It would be great if you provide me any link where i can see the demo of the application using this API.

Comment: @max Thats not something we should have to make the effort to find. You should really go look for yourself and even try playing with the API.

Comment: its not exactly what i want. But it is helpful , i can make use of it. Thank You guys for your support

Comment: I got the solution for editing. I used **CKEdiotr**. It is very good editor. Exactly what i was looking for. But i am still struggling for fetching Word documents on jsp. Now i want to convert word document to html and then display html content to jsp. Can anyone suggest some solution?

http://ckeditor.com/